# QGIS exporting all labels

Tags: qgis, export

I am no hardcore user, I just need some files for a Map which I want to rework in Illustrator. My Citymap has all Streetnames displayed in a view of 1:1000 - But I need to export that to 1:40.000 -> but as soon as I zoom out or I export the file to PDF or DXF, only a couple of names appear (I read about a placement map conflict)

How can I get ALL of the street names into my exported file?

Comment: Turn off conflict resolution

Comment: Thanks, but where can I do that? In the properties of this layer, I deactiveated the overlapping option and set the textsize to 4...but after expporting to pdf, aome labels still are missing, even though i can see them online.  Thanks